# Animator set float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am beginner in developing a game in unity3d. I just found a script for moving a character. So, I'm just confused a little bit in this script. Here's the code that I don't understand.

```
if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") == 0 && Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") == 0) {

       animator.SetFloat ("PlayerState", IDLE);
}
```

I don't understand the line: `animator.SetFloat("PlayerState", IDLE);`

What is PlayerState and IDLE? I know it's a parameter. Is IDLE a variable? How does it works? Can you enlighten me guys?

PS: On the source code that I found, you can't actually see any variables.

**Added Code**

Another code that I don't understand. Assume that the player holds the LShift and W key then the character will run, right? How did the script checks the animator if the character will run? Another thing is, since I have a variable RUN which has a value of 4f, will I remove the line moveSpeed = 4f; or not?

Here is the script:

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
    if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") > 0) { 

        moveSpeed = 4f;

        Quaternion turnAngle = Quaternion.Euler (0, centerPoint.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        character.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (character.rotation, turnAngle, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
        animator.SetFloat ("PlayerState", RUN);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably some variable `float IDLE = 0f`

Comment: 1. If you have a new question please open a new one. 2. In this case don't, I'ld rather suggest you take a step back and watch some tutorials on the basics of c# and Unity.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation is your friend. The method you are talking about is explained in detail [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetFloat.html).

Basically `animator` variable is a reference to `Animator` object, which you created using Unity's Animator. Here is a picture to the menu I am talking about.[image]

"PlayerState" in your example code is an condition you create in Unity's Animator. In the picture I pasted the condition is "horizontalSpeed". Most probably `IDLE` is defined somewhere else in the code you pasted, and must be a value which will set the animation to `IDLE` state such as `float IDLE = 0f`

Comment: What if the code is animator.SetFloat ("PlayerState", RUN); Should I create a variable in script like this one; public float RUN = 4f; ?

Comment: @J.Wujeck yes, that's correct. _PlayerState_ is a parameter in the referenced Animator, and animations will play based on the conditions of the Animator animation transitions. These conditions are based on the parameters.

Comment: Hi guys. I just added some code above. Can you explain it to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not wrong! i think this setfloat function will only work within the update function.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I know you do not have enough reputation to comment yes, but M.A. is correct, this answer really belongs in a comment.  Please consider fleshing out your post to answer the question completely.